# Как грамотно отправить 2-3 запроса android

Tags: java, android, rxjava

Стоит задача, отправить пару запросов, получить с этих запросов данные, обработать их (данные из 2-3 запросов) и отправить в адаптер( например)

Каким образом это правильно и красиво сделать?
Насколько я знаю, для таких задач используется RxJava, хотелось бы чтобы привели пример правильного решение с использованием Rx и без использование Rx.

Comment: "Насколько я знаю, для таких задач используется RxJava" Да ладно? Кто вам такую чушь сказал! AsyncTask, а еще лучше Thread. Отправляет же? Отправляет. А лучшее - враг хорошего.

Answer (score 3):

Если вам нужно соеденить ответы этих запросов то вполне подойдет оператор `concat` 
Вот небольшая демонстрация

```
 final String[] aStrings = {"A1", "A2", "A3", "A4"};
        final String[] bStrings = {"B1", "B2", "B3"};

        final Observable<String> aObservable = Observable.fromArray(aStrings);
        final Observable<String> bObservable = Observable.fromArray(bStrings);

        Observable.concat(aObservable, bObservable)
                .subscribe(getObserver());
```

На выходе получим  поток данных 
спрерва `"A1", "A2", "A3", "A4"` а затем  `"B1", "B2", "B3"`

Так же можно использовать оператор `merge`

```
 Observable.merge(aObservable, bObservable)
                .subscribe(getObserver());
```

тогда на выходе получим поток данных

```
"A1", "B1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "B2", "B3"
```

или же `zip`

```
Observable<String> stringObservable1 = Observable.just("Hello", "World");
Observable<String> stringObservable2 = Observable.just("Bye", "Friends");

Observable.zip(stringObservable1, stringObservable2, new BiFunction<String, String, String>() {
    @Override
    public String apply(@NonNull String s, @NonNull String s2) throws Exception {
        return s + " - " + s2;
    }
}).subscribe(new Consumer<String>() {
    @Override
    public void accept(String s) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
});
```

на выход получим

```
Hello - Bye
World - Friends
```

Я б не стал писать это чисто андроид потоками ибо это ресурсаемко советую использовать rxJava.

Comment: Хотелось бы узнать, следующее, при использовании android потоков , мы отправляем первый запрос, а потом второй запрос)

Но так как нам нужно объединить данные, то мы должны каким-то образом обратиться к параметрам тогда, когда эти запросы уже отработали и вернули ответ.

И вот как это лаконично реализовать?

Ставить задержку?
 Или как?

Comment: @Антон что имеется ввиду под андроид потоками ? тоесть вы не используете  rx  а используете  android java потоки ?ё

Comment: @Антон Да нет ,rx это и есть поток данных, он сам пойдет первый запрос обработает , потом пошлет 2 запрос обарботает и вам даст готовые данные 2х потоков в этом и есть его прелесть )а вот чисто java или андроид методами это сделать геморойно и не это очень низкоуровнево

Comment: Вот, я бы и хотел получить полный ответ, чтобы сравнить геморойный вариант с потоками(без рх) и нормальный вариант с Рх